# PostgreSQL How to use a function in select statement

Tags: postgresql, function, select

I have a SQL table having two columns 'Product_Type' and 'Product_SubType'. A product has a unique name defined based on combining the type and subtype. But the table does not defined the product name. When I query the table, I would like to have the product name presented.
So I am trying to create a function containing cases of different types and output a product name in a select statement:

```
create function getNameByTypes( MainType varchar, SubType varchar)
    return varchar as $$
    declare TypeName varchar;
    begin
    TypeName = case MainType
        when 'type_I' then
            case SubType
                when 'sub_type_1' then 'TypeName1'
                when 'sub_type_2' then 'TypeName2'
            end
            else 'unknown_type' end;
    return TypeName;
    end;
    $$
```

And use the function like:

```
select *, getNameByParams(Product_Type, Product_SubType) as TypeName
where id = 'ABC'
```

I am getting an error `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "return"`. My question is: what is the correct way to create the function and use the function to query?

Comment: what table are you selecting from? and do you even want a function, or just put the case statement directly into your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must change **return** varchar clause for **returns** varchar in functions definition, and missing the function language, see the following:

```
create function getNameByTypes( MainType varchar, SubType varchar)
returns varchar as $$
declare TypeName varchar;
begin
TypeName = case MainType
    when 'type_I' then
        case SubType
            when 'sub_type_1' then 'TypeName1'
            when 'sub_type_2' then 'TypeName2'
        end
        else 'unknown_type' end;
return TypeName;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

And use with your table in from clause:

```
   select *, getNameByParams(Product_Type, Product_SubType) as TypeName from your_table
 where id = 'ABC'
```